# Migration does not generate the name change of the properties when I use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new at this. I'm developing a solution with a Core project ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Core) .

It generates the initial smooth migration : the database created in **PostgreSQL** with tables , keys and indexes. He added the seed properly.

I'm working on a project with the Code First option . When you run the command to add the migration, the file is generated with the code in the Up and Down methods but does not generate the syntax for change of name of the property .

I tried creating annotations on the one hand and the change of name of the property on the other, and the latter migration run the Up and Down methods are generated empty.

Original class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Estudiante
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Apellido { get; set; }

        public string PrimerNombre { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaInscripcion { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Inscripcion> Inscripciones { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Modified class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Estudiante
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Apellido { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Column("nombre")]
        public string PrimerNombre { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime FechaInscripcion { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Inscripcion> Inscripciones { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I ran **dotnet ef migrations add FormatoEstudiante** and **dotnet ef update datababse**. The result of migration is this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Migrations
{
    public partial class FormatoEstudiante : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "primernombre",
                schema: "public",
                table: "estudiante",
                maxLength: 50,
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "apellido",
                schema: "public",
                table: "estudiante",
                maxLength: 50,
                nullable: true);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "primernombre",
                schema: "public",
                table: "estudiante",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "apellido",
                schema: "public",
                table: "estudiante",
                nullable: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Npgsql": "3.1.7",
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.0.1"},

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-    final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "net450",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Migration did not recognize the name change of the column. I do not know if it's a problem in the code or because EF Core with Npgsql still does not support annotation.

Any ideas?

Thank you...

Comment: This is probably an issue in the Npgsql provider - I know there are still some bugs around some migration operations. Can you please open an issue in https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL and link to it here?

Comment: Hi Shay. 
I posted this problem where you said . We'll see what happens during these days. Thank you. https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/87